# only start functions when all previous functions returned false

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new at javascripts so forgive me if this seems obvious but what I want is to start a second function oly if all the condtitions of the previous function actions returned false

```
function validateForm()
{
    var file = document.getElementById('file');
        if (file.files[0].size >= 11000000) {

        alert('File too Big');
        return false;
    }

    var x=document.forms["myForm"]["title"].value;
         if (x==null || x==""){

        alert("First name must be filled out");
        return false;
    }

    // if both returned false then start this function:

    function start_Uploading(){
        document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = 'Loading...';

       return true;
    }
```

the html:

```
<input type='submit'  onclick="return validateForm();">
```

Comment: Please indent your code properly, it is quite unreadable.

Comment: if both what returned false?  Your two validation blocks?  Your {}'s don't match up so I'm not sure what your code actually looks like.  Please clean it up and re-align your brackets so we know what's going on.  Thanks

Comment: Why would you want to perform the upload action when the form validation fails?

Comment: It is impossible that both return statements are executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your return values end the function call.  You just want to set a variable to see if the input is valid.  You can then check and see if the isValid is true, and call your function from there.

Also worth noting in your original code that

```
function start_Uploading(){...}
```

doesn't actually run the function, it just defines it.  You need `start_uploading()` to execute the function.

```
function validateForm()
{
    var isValid = true;
    var file = document.getElementById('file');
    if (file.files[0].size >= 11000000) {
        alert('File too Big');
        isValid=false;
    }

    var x=document.forms["myForm"]["title"].value;
    if (x==null || x==""){
        alert("First name must be filled out");
        isValid=false;
    }

    // if both returned false then start this function:

    function start_Uploading(){
        document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = 'Loading...';
        return true;
    }
    if(isValid){
        start_Uploading();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can only return once from a function, so you would have to return a binary AND of the false values:

```
function validateForm()
{
    var condition1;
    var condition2;

    if(...) condition1 = false;
    if(...) condition2 = false;

    return (condition1 && condition2);
}
```

This is how you would start a function if validateForm returned false:

```
if(!validateForm())
{
     // Execute your function
     start_Uploading();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Call this function, it will check the first function and second function  values and if they are returning false, then start_Uploading() function will execute:

```
function sampleFunction() {
                if(!firstFunction() && !secondFunction()){
                    start_Uploading();
                } 
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery way:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#myForm").submit(function() {
    if ($("#file")[0].files[0].size >= 11000000) {
        alert('File too Big');
        return false;
    }

    if ($("#myForm input[name=title]").attr("value") == ""){
        alert("First name must be filled out");
        return false;
    }

    $('#message').html('Loading...');
    return true;
})
</script>
<form id="myForm">
    <input type='submit'>
</form>
```

Comment: the question wasn't tagged with jQuery, and he doesn't mention using it.

Comment: I know but it's easier and faster to code. I think it's a good idea for him to start using jQuery.